# Store uploaded file in Express in any path in the system except project public folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I am uploading file from front end which is made in React and get it inside Express js. But now if I am storing it inside Express then that file is stored inside public folder.

If I want to store that files in non public folder that can be any path in my system, then how to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take image as base64 String from react client and decode the image string using given below code in backend. Then store the image in any folder.Try this may be it's help you

```
  var fs = require('fs');
  var path = require('path');
  var ID = req.body.id;
  var DOC = req.body.doc;   //Base64 Image String

      var dir = './myapp//asset/'+ID;
      if (!fs.existsSync(dir)){
        fs.mkdirSync(dir);
      }

  var base64Data1 = DOC.replace(/^data:image\/jpg;base64,/, "");
    require("fs").writeFile( val= './myapp/asset/'+ID+'/'+ID+'_1'+'.jpg',base64Data1,'base64', function(err) {
   });

   var absolutePath1 = path.resolve(val);
   var abs1 = JSON.stringify(absolutePath1);
   var v1 = abs1.replace(/"/g,"");
```

If you working with normal Image then you can do this

```
 var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path'),
   busboy = require("then-busboy"),
   fileUpload = require('express-fileupload'),
   app = express(),
   bodyParser=require("body-parser");

    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'asset')));
    app.use(fileUpload());


      function(req, res){
     message = '';
      if(req.method == "POST"){

       if (!req.files)
            return res.status(400).send('No files were uploaded.');

    var file = req.files.uploaded_image;
    var img_name=file.name;

     if(file.mimetype == "image/jpeg" ||file.mimetype == "image/png"||file.mimetype == "image/gif" ){

          file.mv('E:/asset/images/upload_images/'+file.name, function(err) {

              if (err)

                return res.status(500).send(err);
                    var sql = "INSERT INTO `users_image`( `image`) VALUES ('" + img_name + "')";

                        var query = db.query(sql, function(err, result) {
                             res.send('profile');
                        });
                   });
      } else {

        res.render('index.ejs',{message: message});
      }
     } else {
     res.render('index');
    }

 };
```

Comment: The updated code that you have shared with me, in that you have written this line : " file.mv('asset/images/upload_images/'+file.name, function(err) {" in which you have given your project path for asset folder. Now I want to give another path like "D:\files". So how can we give D drive path ?

Comment: Instead of this one 'asset/images/upload_images/ ' you can write full directory path for storing the image like: 'E:/asset/images/upload_images' or you can change as per requirement. Let me know if it's work. @RiyaSoni

Comment: Welcome :) @RiyaSoni